# Using KeyListener to keep track of what textField was used last?

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton, jtextfield

I've got a very simple Java program designed to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa. However right now I only have it set up to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius and i'm having trouble figuring out how to go about making it work both ways.

In the end i'd like the user to be able to type into either text field and have the program know which formula to use based on whatever textfield was altered last. I'd like to use the KeyListener function from Java for this, but after reading the documentation on it i'm fairly confused on how to go about this. I know i'm supposed to add them to the textFields, but it's constructor is a throwing me off.

Here's my code so far, if someone could explain how to incorporate this into my main class i'd be really appreciative!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Convert extends JFrame
{
   private JTextField jtfFahr = new JTextField(10);
   private JTextField jtfCels = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton jbConvert = new JButton("Convert");

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new Convert();
   }

   public Convert()
   {
      setTitle("Convert");
      setSize(400, 125);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel jpNorth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
         jpNorth.add(new JLabel("Fahrenheit", JLabel.RIGHT));
         jpNorth.add(jtfFahr);
         jpNorth.add(new JLabel("Celcius", JLabel.RIGHT));
         jpNorth.add(jtfCels);
      add(jpNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      JPanel jpSouth = new JPanel();
         jpSouth.add(jbConvert);
      add(jpSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      Converter cvt = new Converter(jtfFahr, jtfCels);
      jbConvert.addActionListener(cvt);

      setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Here's the class that actually implements the actions as well:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Converter implements ActionListener
{
   private JTextField jtfDegF;
   private JTextField jtfDegC;

   public Converter(JTextField _jtfDegF, JTextField _jtfDegC)
   {
      jtfDegF = _jtfDegF;
      jtfDegC = _jtfDegC;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {
      if()
      {
         double degF = Double.parseDouble(jtfDegF.getText());
         double degC = (degF - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0;
         jtfDegC.setText(String.format("%.2f", degC));
      }
      else
      {
         double degC = Double.parseDouble(jtfDegC.getText());
         double degF = (degC * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32;
         jtfDegF.setText(String.format("%.2f", degF));
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see it isn't complete yet due to not knowing how to pose the 'if' element.

Any simple explanation on how to implement addKeyListener to this would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Never add a KeyListener to a JTextField as these are very low-level listeners and use of them can undermine the text component's normal functioning.

Usually we would recommend listening to the JTextField's Document, but in your situation a much simpler solution presents itself:

Why not simply add ActionListeners to both. When the user presses enter on either field, its own ActionListener will be called and you can then decide which conversion to do.

For example, a simple example that doubles or halves a number entered

```
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextFieldListener extends JPanel {
    private JTextField field1 = new JTextField(15);
    private JTextField field2 = new JTextField(15);

    public TextFieldListener() {
        field1.addActionListener(e -> {
            String text1 = field1.getText();
            try {
                int value1 = Integer.parseInt(text1);
                String text2 = String.valueOf(2 * value1);
                field2.setText(text2);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                String title = "Number Format Error";
                String message = "Text must be numeric";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(field1, message, title, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                field1.setText("");
            }
        });
        field2.addActionListener(e -> {
            String text2 = field2.getText();
            try {
                int value2 = Integer.parseInt(text2);
                String text1 = String.valueOf(value2 / 2);
                field1.setText(text1);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                String title = "Number Format Error";
                String message = "Text must be numeric";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(field1, message, title, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                field2.setText("");
            }
        });

        add(field1);
        add(field2);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Field Listener");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TextFieldListener());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd really like to, I could complete the program easily like that and be on my way, but if I use a KeyListener I get an entire 2 points added to my average at the end of the semester which could be the difference between an A or a B for me. So i'm trying to do it the hard way. I read the Java API for KeyListener but i'm not sure how to implement it in this situation...

Comment: @AbbeyS And when I paste text into your textfield, it will break your code. Maybe convince your instructor that you've done it a better way and deserve more then 2 additional points, or your instructor should find a new job not teaching programming, whichever

Comment: @AbbeyS: again, I recommend against use of KeyListener, but if you need to use it then why not first try so yourself? For one you've nothing to lose, and for two, we'll then have a much better idea of what you might be doing wrong. Otherwise the question devolves into a "please code this keylistener for me" which I'm sure is not your intention.